# Разница между процесом и службой

Tags: администрирование

Всем привет. Скажите пожалуйста какая принципиальная разница между процесом и службой, например, в Windows XP. Да и вообще в любой другой. Это ведь очень похожие понятия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Служба - это процесс, который работает по определенным соглашениям. То есть, любая служба является процессом, но не наоборот. В принципе, любое приложение без gui можно сделать службой.

Приципиальные отличия

- служба не имеет gui (но может иметь приложение, которое будет с ним взаимодействовать)
- служба часто работает от имени системы и работает без участия пользователя.
- служба имеет интерфейс для вызова "запуск"/"останов"/"рестарт".

Comment: спасибо, такое объяснение мне понятно